# Why does MATLAB fail to check the equality of this trigonometric expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

[`isequaln()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequaln.html#d123e212362) is testing symbolic objects for equality as stated in the documentation. However, this is not the case with the following script.

```
syms a
f1=cos(a)^2;
f2=1-sin(a)^2;
isequaln(f1,f2)
ans =
  logical
   0
```

MATLAB does not return the correct answer. What does MATLAB do when comparing equality for symbolic expressions, compare strings (i.e. a typical scenario for regular expressions), or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the documentation page, there is a section called "Tips", which contains the following item:

> `isequaln(A,B)` checks if `A` and `B` are the same size and their contents are **syntactically** the same expression, treating NaN values as equal. To check whether the mathematical comparison `A == B` holds for all values of variables in `A` and `B`, use `isAlways(A == B)`.

(emphasis mine)

[`isAlways`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) does what you want:

```matlab
syms a
f1 = cos(a)^2;
f2 = 1-sin(a)^2;
isAlways(f1 == f2)
```

This outputs `true`.

---

Alternatives:

```
>> simplify(f1-f2)
ans =
0
 
>> simplify(f1==f2)
ans =
symtrue
```